# How would I stop a rabbitmq worker mid script?

Tags: python, node.js, rabbitmq

How my application is structured node.js server sends data to a python worker which then starts a nonstopping script. What would be the approach to make the node.js server at a later time be able to stop the script and make the worker available to receive from the queue again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The secret to stopping consumers from producers is usually to have a poison message.

Some do this through multiple queues and some through a dedicated message understood downstream as to stop consuming (the latter only works with a single worker).

Basically when your python script sees the poison message it immediately shuts down. The reason you might want this on a separate queue is you may need to broadcast the message if you have multiple workers so you will need an exclusive queue per worker.

As far starting the script it maybe best just to leave workers running and have them wait for a restart message.

Otherwise you could make an observer worker or controller that takes messages and control processes like restarting the python script but this is fairly complicated.

I believe Celery does a lot this if you are looking for something precanned.

**EDIT** - poison message probably already means something else in AMQP. What I mean is your own poison message.

Since you want to kill something while it is running you are going to have to do it the broadcast way.

For every consumer you are going to actually have two consumers per python script.

One to accept the actual data and one to receive commands to start and stop the data consumer.

If you want to start you could have a broadcast message of (JSON but you could use whatever format you like or you could also use AMQP header properties as well)):

```
   {
      "command" : "start"
   }
```

When you want to stop your producer might send a message like:

```
   {
      "command": "stop"
   }
```

Your consumer callback is going to see if `message.command == 'stop'`.

Once you see that message you call `channel.basicCancel(consumerTag)` **on the consumer that is actually receiving data** as well as actually killing whatever is currently running. The killing whatever is currently running is highly dependent on your setup so I can't really go into that because it could be a separate process or it could be a separate thread or an event if using some event engine. Killing long running processes is inherently tricky.

Every python script should have an exclusive queue for the command consumer if using a topic exchange OR you can use a fanout (aka broadcast) exchange.

The data consumer would share a queue with all other scripts.

Comment: From everything I looked up, it seems a poison message is when a consumer can't handle a message.. how would that help a consumer stop? The consumer wouldnt even get that message because it's already processing the current script as well, no?

Comment: I'm sorry I said poison message as there is probably an official poison message AMQP uses. The term is overloaded. What I mean by poison message is a custom message that you create on your end that signals the end.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using a package like celery to manage this with RabbitMQ as your broker. Celery has a `revoke()` function that can be used to terminate a task.

```
>> from celery.task.control import revoke
>> revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

Since it sounds like you want to stop a task already in process - the revoke request with the terminate option set to True will terminate an already executing task. This is false by default.

For reference:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#commands